Shortening a string in rust for the purpose of debug display
I'd like to shorten some strings for a (debug) display method on a struct.  In this example the user_id member is a long UUID and I don't want to print all of it if it would exceed one line, so I'd like to to limit it to no more than 66 characters on the display.
My first (untested) idea is to use write!(f, "{:>12}: {}", "user_id", &self.user_id[..((65..).filter_map(|x| if self.user_id.is_char_boundary(x) { Some(x) } else { None }).nth(0).unwrap())]) in the format function.  But that may be an infinite loop if the string is <65 bytes in length.
...Still untested but maybe write!(f, "{:>12}: {}", "user_id", if self.user_id.len() < 66 { &self.user_id } else { &self.user_id[..((65..).filter_map(|x| if self.user_id.is_char_boundary(x) { Some(x) } else { None }).nth(0).unwrap())]} )
By way of background, AFAIK in the current scheme the user_id is ASCII so write!(f, "{:>12}: {}", "user_id", &self.user_id[..65]) should work perfectly well (and be a lot easier to understand).  However I want to program slightly defensively and not have the program panic if the user_id includes non-ASCII unicode chars in future.
I'm NOT interested in graphene clusters, i.e. not interested in filling all 66 spaces on the display if there are some complex unicode values in there.
I may be interested in a solution that iterates over chars and collects if that can be done efficiently.
Is what I have so far a decent way to solve the problem?  Is there a better way?  I find it a tedious and opaque way to truncate a string but rust isn't making it easy for me.  (I note https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.ceil_char_boundary seems to be what I need but it's only currently available in nightly, and I can't use that in my current environment.)

"I note ...ceil_char_boundary seems to be what I need"—so then just replicate its definition in your own code?  It's all fully public and stable, save for u8::is_utf8_char_boundary, but that's also trivial to manually inline or extract into a function of your own.

I'd personally go with let end_index = my_string.char_indices().nth(65).unwrap_or(my_string.len()), which should be good enough.

^ but you'd need to .map(|(i, _)| i) because CharIndices::Item is (usize, char)

I also note the same/similar problem at https://users.rust-lang.org/t/truncate-str-to-n-utf-8-chars/86626, but as noted the solution there is O(n) vs. O(1) for what I'm thinking of.

As suggested by eggyal, I ended up more or less copying the ceil_char_boundary code into my project:
  /// Returns a slice of the input string truncated to about index bytes on
  /// a utf8 character boundary, to ensures the slice is a valid &str.
  /// The slice may be up to 4 bytes longer if necessary to match the 
  /// character boundary.  Returns the whole string if the string is
  /// shorter than index.
  fn truncate_at_char_boundary(input: &str, index: usize) -> &str {
      let end = if index > input.len() {
          input.len()
      } else {
          let upper_bound = Ord::min(index + 4, input.len());
          input.as_bytes()[index..upper_bound]
              .iter()
              .position(|b| (*b as i8) >= -0x40) // byte is a char boundary
              .map_or(upper_bound, |pos| pos + index)
      };
      &input[..end]
  }

Then write!(f, "{:>12}: {}", "user_id", truncate_at_char_boundary(&self.user_id, 66) )
